# Delete an item from Done List i was trying to do that in multiple ways

Tags: reactjs

Delete an item from Done List i was trying to do that in multiple ways i tried to filter ID and find it and make the item empty but it's not working with me so if u can tell me how to do that and explain why i should do that i want to understand the way that u did it and why u did it thank you ( BTW function name removeItem in that function i need help )

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Todolist from './Todolist'
import Todoinput from './Todoinput'
import Tododone from './Tododone'
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import uuid from 'uuid'

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    items:[],
    id:uuid(),
    item:"",
    editItem:false,
    isDone:false
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState ({
        item: e.target.value
      })
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const newItem = {
        id:this.state.id,
        title:this.state.item,
        isDone:false
      };
      const updatedItems = [...this.state.items, newItem];
      this.setState ({
        items:updatedItems,
        id:uuid(),
        item:"",
        editItem:false
      })
    }
    handleEdit = id => {
      const doneItems = this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
      const selectedItem = this.state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
      this.setState({
        items: doneItems,
        item: selectedItem.title,
        id: id,
        editItem: true
      });
    };
    handleDone = id => {
      const newItems = [...this.state.items];
      const item = newItems.find(item => item.id === id);
      item.isDone = true
      this.setState({
        items:newItems,
      })
    }

    clearList = e => {
      this.setState({
        items:[]
      })
    }
    removeItem = id => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: prevState.data.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      }))
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-8 mt-4">
          <Todoinput item={this.state.item} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} editItem={this.state.editItem} />
          <Todolist 
           items={this.state.items.filter(item => item.isDone === false)}
          handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
          handleDone={this.handleDone}/>
          <Tododone 
          items={this.state.items.filter(item => item.isDone === true)}
          handleDone={this.handleDone} clearList={this.clearList} removeItem={this.removeItem}/>
      </div>
        </div>
          </div>
    )
  }

}
export default App;


/***/

import React from 'react'

class Todoitem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {title,handleEdit,handleDone} = this.props
        return (
           <div>
               <li className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex justify-content-between my-2">
                <h6>{title}</h6>
                <div>
                    <span className="mx-2 text-success">
                    <i className="fa fa-edit" onClick={handleEdit}></i>
                    </span>
                    <span className="mx-2 text-danger">
                    <i className="fa fa-window-close" onClick={handleDone}></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

               </li>
           </div>
        )
    }
}



export default Todoitem


/****/


import React from 'react'
import Todoitem from './Todoitem'

class Todolist extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {items ,handleEdit ,handleDone}=this.props
        return (
           <ul>
               <h3 className="text-capitalize text-center">todo list</h3>
               {
                    items.map(item => {
                        return (
                        <Todoitem 
                        key={item} 
                        title={item.title}
                        handleEdit = {() => handleEdit(item.id)}
                        handleDone = {() => handleDone(item.id)}

                        />
                        )

                    })
                }
           </ul>
        )
    }
}



export default Todolist


/****/

import React from 'react'
import Todoitem from './Todoitem'

class Todoinput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {handleChange,handleSubmit,item,editItem} = this.props
        return (
            <div className="card card-body my-3">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <div className="input-group-prepend">
                            <div className="input-group-text bg-primary text-white">
                                <i className="fa fa-book" ></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control text-capitalize" placeholder="Add An Item"
                         value={item}
                         onChange={handleChange} 
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className={editItem ? "btn btn-block btn-success mt-3" : "btn btn-block btn-primary mt-3"}>
                     {editItem ? 'Edit Item' : 'Add An Item'}</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default Todoinput

/***/

import React from 'react'
import Todoitem from './Todoitem'

class Tododone extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {items,clearList ,removeItem} = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className="text-capitalize text-center">Done Items</h2>
                {
                    items.map(item => (

                <li className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex justify-content-between my-2">
                    <h6>{item.title}</h6>
                    <div className="todo-icon">
                        <span className="mx-2 text-danger">
                            <i className="fa fa-trash" onClick={removeItem}></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                   ))}
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger btn-block text-capitalize mt-5" onClick={clearList}>Clear List</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Tododone
```

so if anyone can help Please i post all the code above if anyone can help me please <3

Comment: It might help to get an answer if you created a minimal reproducible example (e.g. jsfiddle that clearly demonstrates the problem), as well as explaining what exactly the problem is. What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Can you narrow it down to a section of code using a debugger? Does it compile fine? Most people will not want to proof read dozens of lines of code only to find that you have obvious errors, for example (not saying that you do).

Comment: i want to edit this function    removeItem = id => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        items: prevState.items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      }))
    }

Comment: it's not giving any error but it's not deleteing from Done List i want it to delete a singel item from Done List when i click on the trash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a mixup between `data` and `items` in your `removeItem` function. I think you want to update `items`, not `data`:

```
removeItem = id => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    items: prevState.items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
  }))
}
```

The filtering should actually work. Another way to remove a single item from an array is [slice](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/javascript-remove-element-array/), which isn't needed to be called on every item like filter:

```
this.setState(prevState  => ({
  items: prevState.items.slice(indexOfDeleteItem, 1)
}));
```

Comment: this.setState(prevState  => ({
  items: prevState.items.slice(indexOfDeleteItem, 1)
})); i didnt understand these and the first one above it's work without any error but not deleting

Comment: So it seems like you can only delete from the done list. `removeItem` is taking an argument `id`. You have to pass this argument every time you call the function, it is currently missing inside Tododone. Does this help: 

`<i className="fa fa-trash" onClick={() => removeItem(item.id) }></i>`

Answer (score 0):

When you use TodoItem component you can do

```
<Todoitem 
  key={item} 
  title={item.title}
  id={item.id}
  handleEdit={handleEdit}
  handleDone={handleDone}/>
```

And when TodoItem component itself should look like this

```
class Todoitem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {title,handleEdit,handleDone,id} = this.props
        return (
           <div>
               <li className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex justify-content-between my-2">
                <h6>{title}</h6>
                <div>
                    <span className="mx-2 text-success">
                    <i className="fa fa-edit" onClick={() => handleEdit(id)}></i>
                    </span>
                    <span className="mx-2 text-danger">
                    <i className="fa fa-window-close" onClick={() => handleDone(id)}></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

               </li>
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i have no problem in these components all  the work will be in App js and Tododone Component i need to delete a singel item from Done List when i click on trash and other things are working fine